# Apache Flink: add timestamp to filename

Tags: scala, apache-flink, stream-processing

I want to create a BucketingSink in Flink which writes all the files in the same folder, but sets the file name with the current timestamp instead of incrementing counter. For example:

part-0-1514107452000.avro

part-0-1514021052000.avro

...

Here is my code:

```
val sink = new BucketingSink[Tuple2[String, MyType]]("/tmp/flink/")
sink.setBucketer(new MyTypeBucketer(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd--HH")))
sink.setInactiveBucketThreshold(120000) // this is 2 minutes
sink.setBatchSize(1024 * 1024 * 64) // this is 64 MB,
sink.setPendingSuffix(".avro")

val writer: AvroKeyValueSinkWriter[String, MyType] = new AvroKeyValueSinkWriter[String, MyType](parseAvroSinkProperties())
sink.setWriter(writer.duplicate())

def parseAvroSinkProperties(): util.Map[String, String] = {
var properties = new util.HashMap[String, String]()
val stringSchema = Schema.create(Type.STRING)
val myTypeSchema = myType.getClassSchema
val keySchema = stringSchema.toString
val valueSchema = myTypeSchema.toString
val compress = true
properties.put(AvroKeyValueSinkWriter.CONF_OUTPUT_KEY_SCHEMA, keySchema)
properties.put(AvroKeyValueSinkWriter.CONF_OUTPUT_VALUE_SCHEMA, valueSchema)
properties.put(AvroKeyValueSinkWriter.CONF_COMPRESS, compress.toString)
properties.put(AvroKeyValueSinkWriter.CONF_COMPRESS_CODEC, DataFileConstants.SNAPPY_CODEC)
properties
}

class MyTypeBucketer(dateFormatter: SimpleDateFormat) extends DateTimeBucketer[Tuple2[String, MyType]] {
override def getBucketPath(clock: Clock, basePath: Path, element: Tuple2[String, MyType]) = {
  new Path(s"$basePath/${element.f1.getMyStringProp}")
}
```

Does anybody have any idea?
thanks

Comment: So what's the question!

Comment: So I guess the question is how to add filename suffix to final generated file, right? The BucketingSink API can only set suffix of InProgress, Pending and ValidLength state.